# INSERT query not working in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I have a table named `user_data` which contains 5 rows-`id(primary key),name,address,phone,sex`.When I try to insert values into the table  via this query

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_data  VALUES ('Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')");
```

it doesnt work.But When I tried this one,it works.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_data (name,address,phone,sex) VALUES ('Peter_Gregory', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')");
```

I didnt understand what is the real issue behind this.I am using PHP 5.4.7 and XAMPP 1.8.1.

Comment: real issue was you were not telling query what in which fields you were inserting those values second query was right you can insert like  that or by new SET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_data  VALUES ('Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')");
```

Use this when the field is set as `NOT NULL`

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_data  VALUES (NULL, 'Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')");
```

Or use this when the field is set as `NULL`

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_data  VALUES (0, 'Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')")
```

See the mysql manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Since I have made my ID as Not Null,we cannot place NULL for the first column name.I have checked your code,it doesnt work.Anyway I understand the issue.Thanks

Comment: Oke that means that your `id` field not an auto increment is. In that case you should always insert an id.

Answer (score 1):

It does not insert in the first query since it assumes the first value i.e. 'Peter_malik' is for your primary key and it fails.

When you specify the column names in the query it knows which value is for which column.

I addition in the first case i.e.

```
'Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male'
```

will refer to

```
id(pk),name,address,phone
```

So u need to pass the first value as `NULL` so that id gets auto incremented. So the first query should be as

```
VALUES (NULL, 'Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your table has 5 columns `id, name, address, phone` and `sex` your staement has to provide 5 values, one for each column. Since your stament provides only 4 values, you need a column list to tell MySQL which values you do provide.

If your id column is a auto_increment column, you can provide `null` in your values clause.

So you have to say:

```
 INSERT INTO user_data  VALUES (NULL, 'Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male');
```

OR

```
 INSERT INTO user_data (name,address,phone,sex) VALUES 
                       ('Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')
```

Comment: I have made the first column as NOT Null in phpmyadmin.So it doesnt work if I place NULL in the query.

Comment: @AnazA But you must have some auto_increment going on, since you don't need to prove a value for the id column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the id column on your insert statement:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_data VALUES (null, 'Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')");
```

, provided that your id field is set to autoincrement! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the ID also in your first query, it will work without any problem.
Assuming that id=1

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_data  VALUES (1,'Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')");
```

As others said when you have not explicitly mentioned your column names in a query, you have to provide all the values.

Comment: @Anaz A- It does not matter whether it is an auto increment field, you can still insert a value into an auto increment field. what you have to make sure is that you do not duplicate the values. Why downvote?

Comment: @Anaz A - ok no problems, yes it is true we usually do not insert data into an auto increment field. That is why it is set to be auto incremented. I just showed it to make your query works. As others said you can pass null for that field.

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying the following query then...

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_data  VALUES ('Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')");
```

In this query you only inserting 4 values in the table but the table has 5 field so it is causing problem because in the above query the value is inserting form first field & the sequence or datatype mismatching in the database because of this this query causing problem .

If u want insert wuthout specifing field then you may use the following query....

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user_data  VALUES (0,'Peter_malik', 'Griffin door',35897,'male')");<br><br>
```

It Will work properly.

and in the your second query you also specifying the field name & corresponding their values so that's query not causing any problem.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to use the second query you mentioned as you are passing a hard-coded value to a PK column. In fact it may not work at all as the PK column maybe auto-number.

Comment: @AhmedSalmanTahir we know that the primary key may be auto-number but in the case of auto-number the affect of the value 0 will be negligible & query will run without causing any problem.